# how to use an instance of a model in another serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, serialization

I'm stuck here and couldn't find solution to proceed my work,

I have 3 models: plans, days, and meals.

This is my Plan Controller I've managed to get the correct answer in the controller, I want it nested and inside the serializer because I'm using URL helper to retrieve my images URLs, is there a possible way to use the `@plan.id` inside the DaySerializer?

```
  def meals
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
    @days = @plan.days
    @meals = Meal.where("plan_id = ? ", @plan.id)
    render :json => { :plan => @plan, :days => @days,
                      :meals => @meals }
  end
```

This is my Plan model

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :days
  has_one_attached :image, dependent: :destroy
end
```

This is my Day model

```
class Day < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :meals
  has_many :plans
end
```

This is my Meal model

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :day
  has_one_attached :image, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I want to show all meals for a specific Plan, to do that I need to use a variable inside the daySerializer but I couldn't find how to do it.

This is my planSerializer

```
class PlanSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :monthly_price, :plan_days

  def plan_days
    object.days.map do |day|
      DaySerializer.new(day, scope: scope, root: false, event: object)
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my DaySerializer which I need to use the instance of the plan inside

```
class DaySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :number, :plan_meals

  def plan_meals
    #how to be able to use this line in Serilizer? !important
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
    object.meals.map do |meal|
      if meal.plan_id == @plan.id
        MealSerializer.new(meal, scope: scope, root: false, event: object)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

target reason response :

```
{
  id: 8,
  name: "Plan1",
  monthly_price: 88,
  plan_days: [
    {
      number: 5,
      plan_meals: [],
    },
    {
      number: 4,
      plan_meals: [],
    },
    {
      number: 3,
      plan_meals: [],
    },
    {
      number: 2,
      plan_meals: [],
    },
    {
      number: 1,
      plan_meals: [
        {
          id: 11,
          name: "test meal",
          calories: 32,
          protein: 32,
          fat: 32,
          carbohydrates: 32,
          plan_id: 8,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

currently it's showing all meals that belongs to each day,

not only the meals with the `plan_id = Plan.find(params[:id])`

Comment: The readme is probally a pretty good place to start. https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable#associations

Comment: Your associations don't make sense; is there a JOIN table tucked away? You've got `Plan has_many :days` **AND** `Day has_many :plans`?? So what is the foreign key? See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: @TomLord actually it does, and there is no join table, for example we have 2 plans A and B, Plan A has 6 days , and plan B has 10 days, each of thoose days hase 5 meals, so to check plan 1 meals we do Plan.find(A).days.meals where meals.plan_id = Plan.find(A), in fact i could get a correct answer using the controller 
  ` def meals
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
    @days = @plan.days
    @meals = Meal.where("plan_id = ? ", @plan.id)
    render :json => { :plan => @plan, :days => @days,
                      :meals => @meals }
  end `

Comment: @MohamedAmineAzaiez This doesn't address the issue I raised. In particular, how can we have `Day has_many :plans`? Does it make sense to run `Day.last.plans`? If so, how does that work?

Comment: Or as I suspect is most likely, this should actually be `Day belongs_to :plan`, and so `Day.last.plan` works. Singular, not plural.

Comment: Also, this wouldn't work either: `Plan.find(A).days.meals`. I'd advise checking your code samples in the rails console to see if they are valid.

Comment: @TomLord i'll explain the difference, if i make a day belongs to a plan in that case each plan plan would have 14 days, wich will be extra unneccesary rows, but if i keep it many to many , a day may have many plans and a plan may have many days, in this case there will be no more than 14 rows in the day model

Comment: @TomLord i only need `@plan = Plan.find(params[:id])` and then i do `@meals = Meal.where("plan_id = ? ", @plan.id)` i've jsut retested it in the console it gives the correc tanswer

Comment: @MohamedAmineAzaiez For the third time, my question was **not about `meals`**. I am *only* talking about `days` and `plans`. I understand that having a many-to-many association would make sense, in which case those relationships should be `has_and_belongs_to_many` (or `has_many through: ...`), not merely `has_many`. See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I think you could use something like this should work.

`ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new`. It actually by itself allows you to pass additional information to your serializer. It does the same as your current code just you are able to explicitly pass new data.

Controller:

```
  def meals
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
    @days = @plan.days
    @meals = Meal.where("plan_id = ? ", @plan.id)
    render :json => { 
      :plan => @plan,
      :days => ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(@days, serializer: DaySerializer, plan_id: @plan.id),
      :meals => @meals
    }
  end
```

And then in `DaySerializer`:

```
class DaySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :number, :plan_meals

  def plan_meals
    object.meals.map do |meal|
      if meal.plan_id == instance_options[:plan_id]
        MealSerializer.new(meal, scope: scope, root: false, event: object)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So in short `ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new` in controller and `instance_options` in serializer to access passed additional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:
How about add meal serializer?

```
class MealSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :calories, :protein, :fat, # etc
end
```

```
class DaySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :number
  has_many :meals, serializer: MealSerializer
end
```

ORIGINAL:

```
class PlanSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :monthly_price, :plan_days
  
  has_many :plan_days, serializer: DaySerializer
end
```

something like this.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer, but that's not the issue, i want to show only the meals wich has plan_id = @plan.id, i need help with the method plan_meals inside the daySerializer

Comment: i already have a meal serializer, the issue is still in the mothed inside the day serializer i updated my question please check it again, thanks